# Google App Engine + Google Drive API causes ERROR:root:php failure (255)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

In my setup I am using PHP (Zend Framework 2). Everything works fine, and also the Exceptions are working in my application properly. The issue is that when I call the Google Drive API (through Google PHP library) my app freezes for about 60seconds and then server log prints out:

```
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

Additionally it starts outputting so much pure php code that PHPStorm complains:

```
too much output to process
```

And the output just does not stop, it just goes on. It seems to output whole code base in the log and makes the local GAE server crash. But what is important is that the first object that is outputted is actually a Google Service Exception:

```
object(Google_Service_Exception)#453 (8) {
  ["errors":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["domain"]=>
      string(6) "global"
      ["reason"]=>
      string(8) "notFound"
      ["message"]=>
      string(60) "File not found: xxxxxxx"
      ["locationType"]=>
      string(5) "other"
      ["location"]=>
      string(4) "file"
    }
  }
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(320) "{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: xxxxxxx",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "file"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: xxxxxxx"
 }
}
```

My question is what the hell is happening? Why when there is an exception or error on the Google Drive Client side, this happens every time. Otherwise it is working perfectly. Shouldn't it just throw the exception? I am lost.

Comment: Seems the problem is with the actual output that the Google Exception is outputting. It is var_dumping exception + whole code base, which it kinda of absurd. That huge output makes the PHPStorm's own "App Engine for PHP" run configuration crash. If running the python dev server from the console, var_dump omits the rest of the code thus prevents the server from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. Problem was that Zend Framework 2 config was dumping whole error data when error occurred. For some reason that was not an issue with other exceptions, but with Google PHP library the dumps were huge, thus causing server crash.

Comment: If my memory recalls it, I catched the requests that went to Google Drive PHP library with the `try catch` statements and prevented google's own  exceptions to be printed out. Not best solution, but if updating Google Drive PHP library does not solve this issue already, that is one way to go.